Adding new taxonomy in advanced search and float search
I'm working on adding a new taxonomy called "Sorts" to my theme. I successfully added this taxonomy under properties, but I'm encountering some issues. In the advanced search form on the front end, the taxonomy column is blank and does not display any dropdown menu, even though I have added two options to the taxonomy. Additionally, the taxonomy doesn't appear in the floating search or when using Elementor to add an advanced search. I need the "Sorts" taxonomy to function properly in the advanced search, floating search, and advanced search results. Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?
Here is the code I'm using:
Functions.php file:
    add_action('init', 'wpestate_create_sorts_taxonomy', 30);

if (!function_exists('wpestate_create_sorts_taxonomy')) {

    function wpestate_create_sorts_taxonomy() {
        register_taxonomy('sorts', 'estate_property', array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => esc_html__('Sorts', 'wpresidence-core'),
                'singular_name' => esc_html__('Sort', 'wpresidence-core'),
                'search_items' => esc_html__('Search Sorts', 'wpresidence-core'),
                'all_items' => esc_html__('All Sorts', 'wpresidence-core'),
                'edit_item' => esc_html__('Edit Sort', 'wpresidence-core'),
                'update_item' => esc_html__('Update Sort', 'wpresidence-core'),
                'add_new_item' => esc_html__('Add New Sort', 'wpresidence-core'),
                'new_item_name' => esc_html__('New Sort Name', 'wpresidence-core'),
                'menu_name' => esc_html__('Sorts', 'wpresidence-core'),
            ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'sorts'),
        ));
    }

}

searchform file:
 <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Type Keyword', 'wpresidence' ); ?>" />
    
    <!-- Sorts Dropdown -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sorts"><?php esc_html_e('Sorts', 'wpresidence'); ?></label>
        <?php
        $sorts = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sorts',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ));
        if (!empty($sorts) && !is_wp_error($sorts)) {
            echo '<select name="sorts" id="sorts" class="form-control">';
            echo '<option value="">' . esc_html__('All Sorts', 'wpresidence') . '</option>';
            foreach ($sorts as $sort) {
                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr($sort->slug) . '">' . esc_html($sort->name) . '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <button class="wpresidence_button"  id="submit-form"><?php esc_html_e('Search','wpresidence');?></button>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'wpestate_default_search', 'wpestate_default_search_nonce' ); ?>
</form>

advanced_search_results file:
 <?php
// Template Name: Advanced Search Results
// Wp Estate Pack

if(!function_exists('wpestate_residence_functionality')){
    esc_html_e('This page will not work without WpResidence Core Plugin, Please activate it from the plugins menu!','wpresidence');
    exit();
}

if (    ! isset( $_GET['wpestate_regular_search_nonce'] )  || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['wpestate_regular_search_nonce'], 'wpestate_regular_search' ) ) {
}

global $wpestate_keyword;
global $wpestate_included_ids;
wp_cache_flush();
get_header();
$current_user       =   wp_get_current_user();
$wpestate_options   =   wpestate_page_details($post->ID);
$show_compare       =   1;
$area_array         =   '';
$city_array         =   '';
$action_array       =   '';
$categ_array        =   '';
$id_array           =   '';
$countystate_array  =   '';

$compare_submit         =   wpestate_get_template_link('compare_listings.php');
$wpestate_currency      =   esc_html( wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_currency_symbol', '') );
$where_currency         =   esc_html( wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_where_currency_symbol', '') );
$prop_no                =   intval ( wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_prop_no', '') );
$show_compare_link      =   'yes';
$userID                 =   $current_user->ID;
$user_option            =   'favorites'.intval($userID);
$curent_fav             =   get_option($user_option);
$custom_advanced_search =   wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_custom_advanced_search','');
$meta_query             =   array();
$adv_search_what        =   '';
$adv_search_how         =   '';
$adv_search_label       =   '';
$adv_search_type        =   '';
$adv_search_type        =   wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_adv_search_type','');

$wpestate_prop_unit          =   esc_html ( wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_prop_unit','') );
$prop_unit_class    =   '';
$align_class        =   '';
if($wpestate_prop_unit=='list'){
    $prop_unit_class="ajax12";
    $align_class=   'the_list_view';
}




$adv_search_what    =   wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_adv_search_what','');
$adv_search_how     =   wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_adv_search_how','');
$adv_search_label   =   wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_adv_search_label','');
$adv_search_type    =   wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_adv_search_type','');

if(isset($_GET['elementor_form_id']) && intval($_GET['elementor_form_id'])!=0 ){
        $elementor_post_id              =   intval($_GET['elementor_form_id']);
        $elementor_search_name_how      =   "elementor_search_how_" . $elementor_post_id;
        $elementor_search_name_what     =   "elementor_search_what_" . $elementor_post_id;
        $elementor_search_name_label    =   "elementor_search_label_" . $elementor_post_id;
            
        $adv_search_what    =   get_option($elementor_search_name_what,true);
        $adv_search_how     =   get_option($elementor_search_name_how,true);
        $adv_search_label   =   get_option($elementor_search_name_label,true);
        
        if(isset($_GET['term_id']) && intval($_GET['term_id'])!=0 && isset($adv_search_what['use_tabs'])){
            $term_id_elementor  =   intval($_GET['term_id']);
            $adv_search_what    =   $adv_search_what[$term_id_elementor];
            $adv_search_how     =   $adv_search_how[$term_id_elementor];
            $adv_search_label   =   $adv_search_label[$term_id_elementor];
        }
        
   
}else{
    

    if(isset($_GET['term_counter'])){
        $adv_search_fields_no       =   floatval( wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_adv_search_fields_no') );
        $term_counter               =   intval($_GET['term_counter']);

        $adv_search_what    =   array_slice($adv_search_what, ( $term_counter*$adv_search_fields_no),$adv_search_fields_no);
        $adv_search_how     =   array_slice($adv_search_how,    ($term_counter*$adv_search_fields_no),$adv_search_fields_no);
        $adv_search_label   =   array_slice($adv_search_label,  ($term_counter*$adv_search_fields_no),$adv_search_fields_no);
    }

}


if( !isset($_GET['is2']) ){
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///// type1 or type 3
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if( $custom_advanced_search==='yes' ){
        $args = $mapargs    =   wpestate_search_results_custom ('search');

        $return_custom      =   wpestate_search_with_keyword($adv_search_what, $adv_search_label);
 
        if(isset($return_custom['keyword'])){
            $wpestate_keyword        =   $return_custom['keyword'];
        }

        if(isset( $return_custom['id_array']) ){
            $id_array       =   $return_custom['id_array'];
        }

    }else{
        $args = $mapargs = wpestate_search_results_default ('search');
    }

}else{
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///// type 2 city.area,state
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $args                 = wpestated_advanced_search_tip2();
    $meta_query           = array();
    $features             = array();
    $features = wpestate_add_feature_to_search();
    if(!empty($features)){
      $args['tax_query'][]=$features;
    }

    $mapargs = array(
        'post_type'         =>  'estate_property',
        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
        'nopaging'          =>  'true',
        'cache_results'     =>  false,
        'paged'             =>  $paged,
        'posts_per_page'    =>  30,
    );
    $mapargs=$args;
}


if( isset($_GET['geolocation_lat'])     && $_GET['geolocation_lat']!='' && 
    isset($_GET['geolocation_long'])    && $_GET['geolocation_long']!='' 
   ){

    $geo_lat    = sanitize_text_field ( $_GET['geolocation_lat'] );
    $geo_long   = sanitize_text_field ( $_GET['geolocation_long'] );
    
    if(isset($_GET['geolocation_radius']) && $_GET['geolocation_radius']!=''){
        $geo_rad    =   sanitize_text_field ( $_GET['geolocation_radius'] );
    }else{
        $geo_rad    =   wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_initial_radius','');
    }
    
    

    $args  =$mapargs     = wpestate_geo_search_filter_function($args, $geo_lat, $geo_long, $geo_rad);
}







if( ( isset($_GET['is10']) && intval($_GET['is10'])==10)  ){
    $args    =   wpestated_advanced_search_tip10($args);
    $mapargs =   $args;
}

if( isset($_GET['is11']) && intval($_GET['is11']) == 11 ){
    $allowed_html       =   array();
    $wpestate_keyword   =   esc_attr(  wp_kses ( $_GET['keyword_search'], $allowed_html));
    $args               =   wpestated_advanced_search_tip11($args);
    $mapargs            =   $args;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// order by on searhc pagination
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$order = intval(wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_property_list_type_adv_order',''));
if( isset($_GET['order_search']) && is_numeric($_GET['order_search'] ) ){
  $order= intval($_GET['order_search']);
}

$order_array    =   wpestate_create_query_order_by_array($order);
$args           =   array_merge($args,$order_array['order_array']);





////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// END order by on searhc pagination
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$args['posts_per_page'] =   intval(wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_prop_no_adv_search',''));


// remove sold listings
$args=wpestate_remove_sold_listings($args);





// Print the arguments
echo '<pre>';
print_r($args);
print_r($mapargs);
echo '</pre>';

// Add your taxonomy filter
$tax_query = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'sorts', // replace with your actual taxonomy name
        'field'    => 'slug', // or 'term_id'
        'terms'    => 'your_term_slug_or_id', // replace with the actual term slug or ID
    ),
);

if (!empty($args['tax_query'])) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = $tax_query;
} else {
    $args['tax_query'] = array($tax_query);
}

if (!empty($mapargs['tax_query'])) {
    $mapargs['tax_query'][] = $tax_query;
} else {
    $mapargs['tax_query'] = array($tax_query);
}

if( !empty($id_array)){
    $args=  array(  'post_type'     => 'estate_property',
                'p'           =>    $id_array
            );
    $prop_selection =   new WP_Query( $args);

}else{


    $custom_fields = wpresidence_get_option( 'wp_estate_custom_fields', '');
    if(  $order==0 ){
        add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpestate_my_order' );
    }
    if( !empty($wpestate_keyword) ){
        add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpestate_title_filter', 10, 2 );
    }

    $prop_selection =   new WP_Query($args);

    if(  $order==0){
        if(function_exists('wpestate_disable_filtering')){
            wpestate_disable_filtering( 'posts_orderby', 'wpestate_my_order' );
        }
    }

    if( !empty($wpestate_keyword) ){
        if(function_exists('wpestate_disable_filtering')){
            wpestate_disable_filtering( 'posts_where', 'wpestate_title_filter', 10, 2 );
        }
    }
}



$num                        =   $prop_selection->found_posts;
$property_list_type_status  =   esc_html(wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_property_list_type_adv',''));
$half_map_results           =   0;



if ( $property_list_type_status == 2 ){
    include(locate_template('templates/half_map_core.php'));
    $half_map_results=1;
}else{
    include(locate_template('templates/normal_map_core.php'));
}

if (wp_script_is( 'googlecode_regular', 'enqueued' )) {
    $max_pins                   =   intval( wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_map_max_pins') );
    $mapargs['posts_per_page']  =   intval(wpresidence_get_option('wp_estate_prop_no_adv_search',''));
    $mapargs['offset']          =   ($paged-1)*$prop_no;
    $mapargs['fields']          =   'ids';
    $selected_pins              =   wpestate_listing_pins('blank',0,$mapargs,1,$wpestate_keyword,$id_array);//call the new pins

    wp_localize_script('googlecode_regular', 'googlecode_regular_vars2',
        array(
            'markers2'           => $selected_pins,
            'half_map_results'   => $half_map_results
        )
    );


}
get_footer(); ?>

